# Should I use try-with-resources in mybatis pageHelper?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

In my company team, when we use pageHelper and mybatis, we usually write code like this:

```
    private QueryUatpListResponse getUatpInfoByReq(QueryUatpListRequest req) {
        int pageSize = req.getPagingBounds().getPageSize();
        Page<TUatpConfigPo> uatpConfList =  PageMethod.startPage(req.getPagingBounds().getPageIndex(), pageSize)
                .doSelectPage(() -> uatpConfMapper.queryUatpConfList(req.trans(), null));

        QueryUatpListResponse resp = new QueryUatpListResponse();
        resp.getPagingInfo().setPageSize(pageSize);
        resp.getPagingInfo().setPageIndex(req.getPagingBounds().getPageIndex());
        resp.getPagingInfo().setTotalSize((int) uatpConfList.getTotal());
        uatpConfList.getResult().forEach(uatpConfig ->
            resp.getUatpConfigList().add(new QueryUatpListResponse.UatpConfigInfo(uatpConfig)));
        return resp;
    }
```

but jetbrain IDEA always give tips to ask me use try-with-resources in this code block, :

```
// suggest: 'Page<Object>' used without 'try'-with-resources statement 
        Page<TUatpConfigPo> uatpConfList =  PageMethod.startPage(req.getPagingBounds().getPageIndex(), pageSize)
                .doSelectPage(() -> uatpConfMapper.queryUatpConfList(req.trans(), null));
```

We never use try-with-resources in this condition before, and sometimes we need to query many things at one time, so I want to know should we use try-with-resources in every code block like this?

this is the code how IDEA suggest to do:

```
    private QueryUatpListResponse getUatpInfoByReq(QueryUatpListRequest req) {
        int pageSize = req.getPagingBounds().getPageSize();
        QueryUatpListResponse resp;
        try (Page<TUatpConfigPo> uatpConfList = PageMethod.startPage(req.getPagingBounds().getPageIndex(), pageSize)
            .doSelectPage(() -> uatpConfMapper.queryUatpConfList(req.trans(), null))) {

            resp = new QueryUatpListResponse();
            resp.getPagingInfo().setPageSize(pageSize);
            resp.getPagingInfo().setPageIndex(req.getPagingBounds().getPageIndex());
            resp.getPagingInfo().setTotalSize((int) uatpConfList.getTotal());
            uatpConfList.getResult().forEach(uatpConfig -> resp.getUatpConfigList().add(new QueryUatpListResponse.UatpConfigInfo(uatpConfig)));
        }
        return resp;
    }
```

Comment: usually if a class is marked auto closable then you should use try-with-resources to release the resource and not cause resource starvation

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from my colleague.

after the query statement, the page setting will be automaticlly cleaned, so if i query closely after page setting, it wil be ok if i don't use try-with-resources(the chance of meet exception is very low).

but if there are other codes between page setting and query statement, if any error occurs, the resource will not be automatically cleaned, in this condition, it is recommended to use try-with-resources.